# React Native In App Purchase Android

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm trying to add In App Purchases (or as Google likes to call it; "In App Billing") to my React Native App.

**What I've done:**

1. Created a product in Google Play Console (with identifier "unlock_premium"
2. `yarn add react-native-iap` ([this](https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap) library)
3. Added the code below to a component in my app
4. Tested both with `react-native run-android` on a physical device, and through publishing it to an Alpha test from Google Play Console

Notes: The app is signed and billing permissions are enabled in the manifest file, and the version of `react-native-iap` is 0.3.23.

**The issue:**
When running a debug build the `console.log()` just prints that the product is `undefined`, and the `productInfo` does not display on screen when running the Alpha deployed version (so the product was also undefined there). The `products` variable is just an empty array.

(The `try`-statement seems to succeed since I see no errors printed from it.)

```
import InAppPurchase from "react-native-iap";

const itemSKUs = Platform.select({
    android: [
        "com.kimer.unlock_premium" // I've also tried just "unlock_premium"
    ]
})
...

constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modalVisible: false,
            premiumProduct: undefined
        };
}

...

async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            await InAppPurchase.prepare();
            const products = await InAppPurchase.getProducts(itemSKUs);
            console.log("finished call to get products");
            console.log(products[0]);
            this.setState({premiumProduct: products[0]});
        } catch (err) {
            console.warn(err);
        }
}

...

render() {
        let productInfo;
        if (this.state.premiumProduct !== undefined) {
            productInfo = (
                <Text>{this.state.premiumProduct}
                {this.state.premiumProduct.localizedPrice}
                {this.state.premiumProduct.currency} {this.state.premiumProduct.productID}
                {this.state.premiumProduct.title}
                {this.state.premiumProduct.description}</Text>
            );
        }

        return (
            <View>
                ...
                {productInfo}
                ...
            </View>
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED:**
It is now working for me ! I tried a couple of things but I'm not sure what was key to getting it to work  This is anyways what I did:

1. Reinstalled the package
2. Changed my import statement from `import InAppPurchase from "react-native-iap;" to "import * as InAppPurchase from 'react-native-iap';"`
3. Changed my SKU in the code from "com.kimer.unlock_premium" to "unlock_premium"

Comment: did all those things, still getting an empty array? Any ideas?

Comment: @MayankBaiswar Did you find any solution?

Comment: Dumb side question.. is it possible to test react-native-iap on an android app without a production android merchant account and an approved and deployed app? How? and can this be used to force a user on a  free app to buy a one time license after a week or after using the app 10 times?